# Android Vector drawable size

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am using svgs to generate VectorDrawable for android app ,and i read  [Considerations for SVG and PSD files](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)

> The initial loading of a vector drawable can cost more CPU cycles than the corresponding raster image. Afterward, memory use and performance are similar between the two. We recommend that you limit a vector image to a maximum of 200 x 200 dp; otherwise, it can take too long to draw.

but i have question , what is the recommended *size of svgs* and what size when use in *menu items* **with Pixel** ?

Comment: Please understand that PSD files are **not** vectorial, they are layered bitmaps (and can't be used in Android - directly). A VectorDrawable is described by paths which are then turned into bitmaps. **Before** the conversion, they can be scaled without distorsion. But **after** the conversion, they become bitmaps and have a memory footprint of X*Y*4, as usual.

Comment: is vector paths depend on vector width or height ? or can make image is lower quality ?

Comment: No. Paths give a "base". It can be made very small if you don't need a lot of details. Or very big, if you need more detailed borders. The image quality is not affected. That's the beauty of vectors (SVGs are a **super**set of the VectorDrawables).

Comment: Ok , i have one more question about height ,width ,viewportHeight ,viewportWidth attributes in <Vector ..> , it is initial values or default values ?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html

Comment: does width and height attributes of vector affect memory bitmap size ?

Comment: Ramy, this is called the [help vampire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Comment: i just want to be sure , cause i have unexpected issue :(

Answer (score 0):

For your question in the comments regarding height, width and viewportHeight and viewportWidth:

The ratio of Height to Width should be same as viewportHeight to viewportWidth . Otherwise aspect ratio of the image changes i.e., either it will be too wide or too tall.

If you increase the viewport size while you keep the same pathdata it results in  scaling down of the image.(Also the image gets translated). You can learn better by experimenting with these figures.
Viewport is viewport. Imagine your picture starts at extreme left. and goes 100dp right. If your viewport is 50dp wide then half of your image gets truncated.